# Git pull from heroku

Tags: wordpress, git, heroku, github

How do I pull from heroku?
I have wordpress running in my heroku app and i changed some stuff via the template editor.

I'd like to have these changes also locally.

When i try to pull from heroku i get the message:

```
Already up-to-date.
```

But I don't have these changes locally

Answer (score 1):

It's normal to get the *Already up-to-date* message, since the remote changes weren't commit and pushed.

Since you cannot commit and push from Heroku, you need work locally and then deploy. And that's how you should work at first place.

Answer (score 1):

What did you change with the template editor?  Probably configuration, and not code right?  So if you do a pull from Heroku, you're not going to see changes?  (I'm not familiar with wordpress - but I doubt the template changes result in code changes).  So I guess I'm hypothesising that it's right: there are no changes.

Perhaps what you really want are database changes?

By the way, you can now clone a Heroku app with the new [`heroku git:clone`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clone-heroku-app)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem was when we added pictures they also vanish after pushing. We are now using amazon S3 as image store

Answer (score 0):

What does `git branch -r --no-merged` return? If it returns any branches, it means those branches have changes you don't have in the current branch yet. Merge them to get the changes.

Otherwise, the thing you are pulling does indeed not have any changes. That can mean that the changes you are looking for in another branch.

What you might want to do in that case is `git fetch <heroku>` where heroku is the name of the remote pointing to the heroku repository. That'll fetch all banches from heroku, which you then are able to merge.